# VisualVM - CPU Profiler customization

Tags: performance

I have customized the CPU settings as per my application ie,co.mxxx.** and started CPU profiling in Linux machine. But the profiling seems to be just showing `Profiler Busy` with no results even after an hour. Can somebody tell how to customize the CPU settings and get the desired CPU time?

I would also like to know if there is any other type for single class than the one i have given for CPU profiling. As i'[image: CPU settings Image]m not getting any result out of it.

Comment: A screenshot of your setting would be helpful

Comment: Have added the screen shot